# SQL to LINQ with sub joins and sub queries

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

I am fairly new to LINQ and having issues when converting this SQL to LINQ. Can any one help me achieve this?

```
Select DISTINCT u.ID from 
(Select x.ID from table1 x where x.Info = 0) u
where u.ID not in 
(select c.ID from table1 c where c.Info = 1)
```

I have a table table 1

`ID  Info
1   0
1   1
1   0
2   0
3   1
3   0
4   0
5   1`

I want to return all records that have all Info = 0 so the output for the above table would be 
2, 4

Please share some insights

Comment: When you select an answer you can also give that person an upvote. Also being able to upvote any comments or other answers (that offer differing solutions) that add to your understanding of what you requested; then an upvote is more forthcoming in return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you selected Octaviocci's answer, I would point out there is LINQ that looks like SQL than there are those that use Lambda expressions like his. Here is what a regular Linq statment might look like when your more familiar with T-SQL:

```
var nonEquijoinQuery = (from a in table1
                        let b = from c in table1
                            where c.Info == 1
                            select c.ID
                        where a.Info == 0 && b.Contains(a.ID) == false
                        select a.ID).Distinct();
```

Comment: The selected answer vanished? Glad I could help then. with a different syntax of code. An upvote as well?

Answer (score 1):

This will return only ID's that have all INFO=0

```
var query = from t in context.table1
    group t by t.ID
    into g
    where g.All(i => i.INFO == 0)
    select g.Key;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response. this works great!! thank  you

Comment: You don't need to call `Distinct` here

Comment: I removed `Distinct`

Answer (score 0):

```
var innerQuery = context.Table1.where(z=>z.Info == 1).Select(z=>z.ID)
var query = context.Table1.where(z=>z.Info == 0 && !innerQuery.Any(x=>x==z.ID)).Select(z=>z.ID)
```